# How can I populate a column of a dataframe with information of another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two different dataframes and I need to add informatio of one dataframe into another basede on a column where they share the same values.

Something like this:

DF1:

| Invoices | Client | Product | Product type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | AAAAAA | A1a1 |  |

DF2:

| Product | Product type | Product description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1a1 | Type A1 | description of the product |

The first Dataframe is a list of all invoices over the last year, which has one row for each product in that invoice, I need to add the "Product type" from DF2 on DF1 for each product.

I've tried to use the merge function but it adds the column and that's not what I need to do.

I need to compare the "Product" columns on both DFs and when the value is the same populate DF1 "Product" with DF2 "Product" value.

Comment: it is a merging question day :) one after another ;)

Answer (score 0):

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how ="left", on "Product")